# How to call another function within the same object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let role = {
    test: (variable) => {
        // How do I call toLog(variable) from here?
    },
    toLog: (variable) => {
        console.log(variable);
    }
};
```

I'd like to call the toLog() function within the test() function but I'm unaware how to.

Comment: `role.toLog()` or use a class so you can simply use `this.toLog()`

Comment: [Don't use arrow functions where you don't need them!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572) With method syntax (in the object literal) you could just invoke `this.toLog` as usual.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Standard JS functions use dynamic binding, `this` is dependent on who's calling the method on runtime, so if we call it using `role.test()`, it will bind `this` to `role`.

Arrow functions bind `this` to the current context. For example, if the code was writtern in the browser's console, `this` is bound to the `window` object. This is called **static lexical binding**, which means binding `this` to the closure it was defined in.

If you won't use arrow functions, `this` will point to the object itself when called by `role`:

```js
const role = {
    test(variable){
        this.toLog(variable);
    },
    toLog(variable) {
        console.log(variable);
    }
};

role.test(5);
```

In this case, we don't want to bind `this` to the outer context, so we'll skip the static binding in favor of the dynamic one.

However, if we'll use this method as a callback, dynamic binding will change `this` according to who's running the method. To prevent that, we'll have to use `bind` to create an explicit static binding to `role`.

```js
const role = {
  test(variable) {
      this.toLog(variable);
    },
    toLog(variable) {
      console.log(variable);
    }
};

let test = role.test;

try {
  test(20); // will throw an error - this.toLog is not a function - because this points to window
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}

test = role.test.bind(role);

test(25); // will work because it's staticly binded to role
```

Comment: Really nice explanation thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using arrow functions, using this here will not work but you have your object referenced as `role` so you can call the function as `role.toLog` from your another function i.e. `test` as shown below

```js
let role = {
    test: (variable) => {
        // How do I call toLog(variable) from here?
        role.toLog(`${variable} from test`);
    },
    toLog: (variable) => {
        console.log(variable);
    }
};

role.test('hello world');
```